# How to remove empty key/value pairs from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I am constructing a JSON with key/value pairs that I am sending to the server, if the `Name` field is empty and the `Item_2` field is < 0, then I would like to remove the `Name` field.

I am working with up to 10 nested dictionaries, but only dictionaries 2-10, or 1-9[indexed] will meet this criteria.

`lResults` is my list of results which is dumped into JSON format, when I print  `lResults[0]['SRData']['ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval']['DeadAnimalRemoval'][0]['Name']` only the values print, and I do not see the empty strings, but when lResults is dumped into a JSON I see the blank strings.

The variables in each of the 10 dictionaries might or might not be blank, but the server where I am sending this JSON is either expecting a Name field, or nothing, and the Name field is unique to each dictionary.

Here is my code;

```
    dL311 = dict()
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
    d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
    d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_1)
    d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
    d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_1 )
    d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_1)
    l311.append(d)
    dL311 = dict()
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
    d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
    d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_2)
    d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
    d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_2)
    d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_2)
    l311.append(d)
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
    d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
    d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_3)
    d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
    d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_3)
    d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_3)
    l311.append(d)
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
    d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
    d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_4)
    d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
    d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_4)
    d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_4)
    l311.append(d)
    d = dict()
    d.setdefault("DriverFirstName",last_edited_user )
    d.setdefault("DriverLastName","Aguilar" )
    d.setdefault("LastUpdatedBy", "SANSTAR1")
    d.setdefault("DACType", dar_item_5)
    d.setdefault("Type", "Dead Animal Removal")
    d.setdefault("Name", dar_uid_5)
    d.setdefault("DACItemCount", dar_qyt_5)
    l311.append(d)
 dL311 = dict()
        dL311.setdefault("DeadAnimalRemoval", l311)
        dResult.setdefault("ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval",dL311)
        lResults.append({"MetaData": {}, "SRData": dResult})
```

Result of lResults dumped as JSON, I would like to remove all keys where I would like to construct a condtion which states:

```
if "Name" == " " and DacItemCount < 0:
then remove `Name` key and value
```

JSON of lResults with blank Name fields

```
{
            "MetaData": {}, 
            "SRData": {
                "ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval": {
                    "DeadAnimalRemoval": [
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": "070920151120552101", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                "ReasonCode": "", 
                "ResolutionCode": "A", 
                "SRNumber": "1-20979921"
            }
        }
    ]
    [
        {
            "MetaData": {}, 
            "SRData": {
                "ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval": {
                    "DeadAnimalRemoval": [
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": "070920151119458601", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }, 
                        {
                            "DACItemCount": "0", 
                            "DACType": " ", 
                            "DriverFirstName": "Esri_Anonymous", 
                            "DriverLastName": "Aguilar", 
                            "LastUpdatedBy": "SANSTAR1", 
                            "Name": " ", 
                            "Type": "Dead Animal Removal"
                        }
```

Comment: You really could do with a function to organize this; this way, the filtering and generation of the dictionary are in one or two places.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to solve your problem: after you finished constructing the `l311` list, go through each item (dictionary) and remove keys based on your criteria:

```
l311 = [
    dict(
        DriverFirstName=last_edited_user,
        DriverLastName='Aguilar',
        LastUpdatedBy='SANSTAR1',
        DACType=dar_item_1,
        Type='Dead Animal Removal',
        Name=dar_uid_1,
        DACItemCount=dar_qyt_1),
    dict(
        DriverFirstName=last_edited_user,
        DriverLastName='Aguilar',
        LastUpdatedBy='SANSTAR1',
        DACType=dar_item_2,
        Type='Dead Animal Removal',
        Name=dar_uid_2,
        DACItemCount=dar_qyt_2),
    dict(
        DriverFirstName=last_edited_user,
        DriverLastName='Aguilar',
        LastUpdatedBy='SANSTAR1',
        DACType=dar_item_3,
        Type='Dead Animal Removal',
        Name=dar_uid_3,
        DACItemCount=dar_qyt_3),
    # ...
]

for d in l311:
    if not d['Name'].strip() and d['DACItemCount'] < 0:
        del d['Name']
        del d['DACItemCount']
```